# Visual Studio Development Server 2010 renders partial pages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, aspnet-development-server

I'm working on an ASP.Net web application.  Over the last week the development team has noticed the pages are only partially rendering.  That is when you click on a link, or a button or anything to does a post back the page will render a portion of the way and then IE continues to just clock.  If you attached to the Visual Studio Development Server and pause the process there is no source code to view and the 2 reported steps in the stack trace are "In a sleep, wait, or join" and "External Code".

We have also noticed the View State MAC Validation exception thrown form time to time.  I'm not sure if this is related, but according to research on that error it is caused when the view state is not fully loaded and the page is posted back to the server.

We have not updated anything from an architectural stand point, all references to AJAX and .Net libraries have been the same or months.  This issue has just cropped up over the last week or so.

Has anyone out there had issues with Visual Studio Development Server or know a fix for this?

Comment: do you have EnableViewState set to False any where ?  maybe a masterpage that your missing?

Comment: EnableViewState is set to false on a couple controls throughout the app.  But specifically this seems to just drop the request to the Development Server.  When it happens the browser just has the loading progress icon clocking and pausing the code shows the server is waiting for a request.